# angular2 - Execute template statement from directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I basically want what having an

```
@Ouput() private event = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

does except I need to be able to capture the return value from that statement.

I want to pass the directive a function call that will execute on click and I want the directive to be able to use the return value from that function.

Currently the way I've gotten it working is by passing it as such

```
<button [myDirective]='[theFunction, param1, param2]'></button>
```

but I would like to be able to do

```
<button myDirective='theFunction(param1, param2)'></button>
```

In angular 1 you were able to do this using `$eval` on the string that's passed in. How do you do this in angular 2?

Comment: Have a look a this but I'm unsure it will handle the level of complexity you want: https://github.com/vinayk406/angular-expression-parser